# How to add our own ascx file into dotnetnuke website

Tags: dotnetnuke-module

Now I have created my own ascx file and i want it to add in my dotnetnuke website.
I know that we can add any external module using host\extension\install extension wizard.
but that must be a zip file and this is ascx file.

Can you help me please? Please give me steps.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to get a good foundation of DNN module development: creating a module project, module packaging and the correct techniques in DNN for navigating and data access.  I have a really good training tract on DNNHero.com that gives you the exact steps and plenty of source code.  To read more about it, go [here](http://www.dotnetnuclear.com/articles/tabid/88/ID/15/categoryId/3/How-to-Become-a-Proficient-DNN-Developer-for-Under-80.aspx).